# How to return parent value for each array iteration with jsonpath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm attempting to import some json data into grafana via the JSON API.

Here's a snippet of the json structure I'm working with:

```
[
  {
    "origin": "TS",
    "id": "M8C8E02434D442725422CCB337057792F",
    "type": "1.5.1:1",
    "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapiM8C8E02434D442725422CCB337057792F",
    "source": "destinationhost01.our.domain.net",
    "target": "destinationhost01.our.domain.net-0",
    "probe": "cdm",
    "for_computer_system": {
      "id": "14873",
      "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapi/devices/14873",
      "name": "destinationhost01.our.domain.net",
      "ip": "10.1.1.16"
    },
    "for_device": {
      "id": "D4F3D290D787D3FA4E7CD2824BFA6B1C8",
      "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapi/devices/D4F3D290D787D3FA4E7CD2824BFA6B1C8"
    },
    "for_configuration_item": {
      "id": "CCE5006B73554FE7D307C1A355429286A",
      "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapi/TBD/CCE5006B73554FE7D307C1A355429286A",
      "name": "CPU-0",
      "qosName": "QOS_CPU_MULTI_USAGE",
      "description": "Individual CPU Usage",
      "unit": "%"
    },
    "uimMetricDefinition": null,
    "minSampleValue": 61.17,
    "maxSampleValue": 72.78,
    "meanSampleValue": 64.864,
    "sample": [
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543832,
        "value": 61.17,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543772,
        "value": 63.52,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543712,
        "value": 62.79,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543652,
        "value": 64.06,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543592,
        "value": 72.78,
        "rate": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "origin": "TS",
    "id": "M9D90857B9F9BE73EB15912D3314DB2DA",
    "type": "1.5.1:1",
    "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapiM9D90857B9F9BE73EB15912D3314DB2DA",
    "source": "destinationhost01.our.domain.net",
    "target": "destinationhost01.our.domain.net-1",
    "probe": "cdm",
    "for_computer_system": {
      "id": "14873",
      "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapi/devices/14873",
      "name": "destinationhost01.our.domain.net",
      "ip": "10.1.1.16"
    },
    "for_device": {
      "id": "D4F3D290D787D3FA4E7CD2824BFA6B1C8",
      "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapi/devices/D4F3D290D787D3FA4E7CD2824BFA6B1C8"
    },
    "for_configuration_item": {
      "id": "CF1D7A708DD4C6C9D303025AE3D2334AE",
      "self": "https://metricsourcehost01/uimapi/TBD/CF1D7A708DD4C6C9D303025AE3D2334AE",
      "name": "CPU-1",
      "qosName": "QOS_CPU_MULTI_USAGE",
      "description": "Individual CPU Usage",
      "unit": "%"
    },
    "uimMetricDefinition": null,
    "minSampleValue": 59.85,
    "maxSampleValue": 72.31,
    "meanSampleValue": 64.296,
    "sample": [
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543832,
        "value": 59.85,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543772,
        "value": 63.88,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543712,
        "value": 60.17,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543652,
        "value": 65.27,
        "rate": 60
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z",
        "timeSinceEpoch": 1630543592,
        "value": 72.31,
        "rate": 60
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's CPU utilisation for 2 CPU cores from the same host.

Using `$.[*].sample[*].time` and `$.[*].sample[*].value` successfully returns the required time and value data which can be easily graphed:

```
| time                     | value |
| ------------------------ | ----- |
| 2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z | 61.17 |
| 2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z | 63.52 |
| 2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z | 62.79 |
| 2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z | 64.06 |
| 2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z | 72.78 |
| 2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z | 59.85 |
| 2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z | 63.88 |
| 2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z | 60.17 |
| 2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z | 65.27 |
| 2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z | 72.31 |
```

However, it combines all the data with no way to differenciate between the two CPU core data samples.

I've been trying to figure out a way to get a third column utilising the **target** value *for each iteration* of the sample array.

Ideally, the output should look like this when tabled:

```
| target                                 | time                     | value |
| -------------------------------------- | ------------------------ | ----- |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**0** | 2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z | 61.17 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**0** | 2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z | 63.52 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**0** | 2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z | 62.79 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**0** | 2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z | 64.06 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**0** | 2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z | 72.78 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**1** | 2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z | 59.85 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**1** | 2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z | 63.88 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**1** | 2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z | 60.17 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**1** | 2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z | 65.27 |
| destinationhost01.our.domain.net-**1** | 2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z | 72.31 |
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure it's even doable with jsonpath... hence why i'm reaching out to the experts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [JSON API for Grafana](https://marcus.se.net/grafana-json-datasource/) uses the [JSONPath Plus package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus), it's quite easy to accomplish what I was after.

The `^` is able to grab the parent of any matching item. Playing around with this in the [JSONPath Demo](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/demo/) site got me there. You can paste in my example from the original post and test the following queries:

- `$.[*].sample[*].time` obtains the time from each sample.
- `$.[*].sample[*].value` obtains the value from each sample.
- `$.[*].sample[*].value^^^^.for_configuration_item.name` is the special sauce that will grab the `for_configuration_item.name` *for each sample*

Providing these three queries to Grafana makes a table like this:

| core | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CPU-0 | 2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z | 61.17 |
| CPU-0 | 2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z | 63.52 |
| CPU-0 | 2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z | 62.79 |
| CPU-0 | 2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z | 64.06 |
| CPU-0 | 2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z | 72.78 |
| CPU-1 | 2021-09-02T00:50:32.000Z | 59.85 |
| CPU-1 | 2021-09-02T00:49:32.000Z | 63.88 |
| CPU-1 | 2021-09-02T00:48:32.000Z | 60.17 |
| CPU-1 | 2021-09-02T00:47:32.000Z | 65.27 |
| CPU-1 | 2021-09-02T00:46:32.000Z | 72.31 |

From there, using the **Group by** feature in the **Experimental** tab on the `core` column graphs the values exactly as required.